# Flex multi-page form for Android

Tags: android, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flashbuilder4

I want to use a flex multi-page form on thew newly released [Adobe AIR for android platform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac25d3d8c712b2d86751e-8000.html). I have a sequence of 30-40 screens on the form and the user can exit in between(storing the partial data entered). Is there a sample application for this, or can someone tell me the architecture to build such an application with lots of views? I want to store the data both on the device([sqlite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5497-7fb4.html)) as well as a remote web server.
The closest help I found was [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=navigators_5.html)

Comment: That's *a lot* of screens for a mobile app...

Comment: yep,thats the project requirement!!

Comment: even if it's a 'requirement' I would try to talk to the manager/UX person to try to simplify.  Nobody in their right minds will go through 40 screens...  But I digress...

Comment: @J_A_X: thanks for the suggestion..not a practical everyday app. some business workflow apps sometimes have such weird requirements for workers to be in compliance with protocols. A lot of the views are skippable though...

Answer (score 1):

Architecture is up to the solution you're trying to implement.  In this case, it's as simple as having a centralized data model somewhere that either binds or sets the data on each view so that it can be reused across all views.

If I were you, I'd look at [RobotLegs](http://robotlegs.org/) to accomplish this using dependency injection since it leaves the door open for more complex architectural situations in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't going to be any examples out there to do *exactly* what you want. There are several Flex for Android tutorials out there though. Here are a few to get you started:

- [Intro to Flex 4.5 Android Programming](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/intro-to-flex-4-5-android-programming/)
- [Tutorial: Flex for Android in 90 Minutes](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/tutorial-flex-android-90?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20zones/ria%20%28RIA%20Zone%29)
- [Developing a mobile application with Flex 4.5, AIR 2.5, Flash Builder Burrito, WCF and the Entity Framework](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/alexb/archive/2010/11/29/developing-a-mobile-application-with-flex-4-5-air-2-5-flash-builder-burrito-wcf-and-the-entity-framework.aspx)
- [Swipe Gestures using Flex 4.5 Hero/Burrito on Android](http://www.asgarddesigns.com.au/2011/04/swipe-gestures-using-flex-4-5-hero-burrito-on-android/)
- [Android Components for Flex 4.5](http://www.yapiodesign.com/blog/2011/05/13/android-ui-components-for-flex-4-5/)